# How to animate element move up after removing previous elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have this sample code:

```
<ul>
  <li class="class1">row1</li>
  <li class="removeme">row2</li>
  <li class="removeme">row3</li>
  <li class="removeme">row4</li>
  <li class="class1">row5</li>
</ul>

//Javascript
$('.removeme').remove();
```

How do I make the row5 element animate its movement up once all the removeme elements are removed? My css3 transitions are also set.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T8cs4/

Comment: Did you get look at the answers? Leave a comment/upvote and mark it as answered if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you have set in css3, but below is what you can do with jQuery.

```
$('.removeme').animate({height: 0}, 2000, function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MwYH5/

If you want it removed **one by one**, then you can chain like below.

## **DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MwYH5/1/

```
(function removeNext(jq) {
    jq.eq(0).animate({height: 0}, 1000, function () {
        $(this).remove();
        (jq = jq.slice(1)).length && removeNext(jq);            
    });
})($('.removeme'))
```

**Ref:** http://paulirish.com/2008/sequentially-chain-your-callbacks-in-jquery-two-ways/#comment-24910

Answer (score 0):

You could put the "remove me" li's in a container (like a span) and collapse that container.

```
$(container).fadeTo(200,0).animate({height: 0});
```

Something like that.